# Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have a Node /w Typescript REST API, I have signup method which creates a user and responses with the created users firstName, lastName, email.

The problem is I am having this typescript error that says "Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type 'SavedUser': firstName, lastName, email".

I believe its something with adding mongoose.Document type in my SavedUser Interface, i am not sure tho, thanks for the help!

**Error ScreenShot:**
[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
    interface SavedUser {
        firstName: string 
        lastName: string
        email: string
    }

    ...

    public async signUp(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void | Response> {
        const salt: string = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        const hashedPassword: string = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)

        const user = new User({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        try {
            const { firstName, lastName, email }: SavedUser = await user.save()

            return res.status(200).send({
                firstName,
                lastName,
                email
            })
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does `user.save()` returns?

Answer (score 8):

I do not know where the problem exactly but this is how I create mongoose schema using TypeScript and it works for me.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface SavedUserDocument extends mongoose.Document {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
}

const SavedUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});
export const SavedUser = mongoose.model<SavedUserDocument>('saveduser', SavedUserSchema);
```

Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

Mongoose returns more on `.save()` then you are currently specifying with the SavedUser interface.

The easiest way of getting all the types from Mongoose, is by using the exported `Document` and extending your interface.

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface SavedUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Thanks for answering I solved it! I mixed [dijkstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858638/dijkstra) and [phw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416908/phw)'s answer and came up with this:**

In my User Model

//user.ts

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255
    },

    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    }
})

export interface SavedUserDocument extends Document {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export const userSchemaModel = model<SavedUserDocument>('User', userSchema)
```

now on my User Controller:

//user.ts

```
import { userSchemaModel, SavedUserDocument } from '../../models/user/user'
...
    public async signUp(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void | Response> {
        const user = new userSchemaModel({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email
        })

        try {
            const { firstName, lastName }: SavedUserDocument = await user.save()

            return res.status(200).send({
                firstName,
                lastName,
                message: 'User created'
            })
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err)
        }
    }
...
```

**I do have a question;**

If I removed the `<SavedUserDocument>` in `model<SavedUserDocument>('User', userSchema)` I would still receive the error, can i have a good explanation of that? i'm still relatively new with Typescript and would be great to get an explanation, Thank you very much!