# Nestjs: Correct schema for array of subdocuments in mongoose (without default _id or redefine ObjectId)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am working with Nest.js and trying to create a Schema with decorators which contain array of sub-document field.

I don't have any troubles, with importing/export the Schema and converting it to a model, until:

[image: Error]

I receive the following error in my `service` file.

After hours of googling, I discover that the real reason is behind the `array` sub-document fields, and only with them. *As soon, as I remove the `members` field. the schema & model will be fine.* And have to do nothing with the solution described [in following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353028/nestjs-type-does-not-satisfy-the-constraint-document), or [any other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370026/type-document-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type) relevant with `extends Mongoose.Document`. (*If you have already done it*)

Most of cases, that I found, are relevant with sub-documents, but not array sub-document. And I'd like to ask:

#### How to correctly create a field with an array of subdocuments in Nestjs via mongoose / Typescript with using of decorators?

And unseed this error:

```
S2344: Type 'Guild' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any, {}>'.   
  The types returned by 'delete(...).$where(...).cast(...)' are incompatible between these types.
   Type 'UpdateQuery<Guild>' is not assignable to type 'UpdateQuery<Document<any, {}>>'.
     Type 'UpdateQuery<Guild>' is not assignable to type '_UpdateQuery<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<Document<any, {}>>>>'.
Types of property '$pull' are incompatible.
  Type 'PullOperator<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<Guild>>>' has no properties in common with type 'PullOperator<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<Document<any, {}>>>>'.
```

My Schema is:

```
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

class GuildMember {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, lowercase: true })
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  id: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  rank: number;
}

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Guild extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, lowercase: true })
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.Array})
  members: GuildMember[]
}

export const GuildsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Guild);
```

#### What have I done.

Various ways including:

- Cover sub-document `Class` with `@Schema()` decorator and adding `extends Document`
- Adding `type:` to field `@Prop()` decorator:

```
  @Prop({ type: [GuildMember] })
  members: GuildMember[]
```

or vice-versa. It's `ok` for primitives, but not for `Class` embedded documents.

- adding `@Prop({ ref: () => GuildMember })`

And following the official NestJs docs:

```
  @Prop({ type: [{ type: MongooseSchema.Types.Array, ref: GuildMember }] })
  members: GuildMember[]
```

It still doesn't help. I thought, that it could be relevant, not just with `mongoose.Document`, but also another type, which is: `mongoose.DocumentArray`

#### Updated:

According to current progress. It seems that problem is relevant with the `field: type` value of default mongoose, not the `@Prop` decorator itself. So even if I write something like that:

```
  @Prop()
  members: Types.Array<GuildMember>
```

it still gives an error. Type is imported from: `import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema, Types } from 'mongoose';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATED:

Working solution:

#### *with redefined _id for other TS primitive:*

```
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema, Types } from "mongoose";
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
class Pet extends Document  {
  @Prop({ type: Number })
  _id: number;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  name: string;
}

export const PetsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Pet);
```

Parent schema array of objects field:

```
  @Prop({ type: [PetsSchema] })
  pets: Types.Array<Pet>;
```

#### *If you want to disable build-in `ObjectId` at all*

Use the following `@Prop` decorator and remove `_id` from child schema:

```
  @Prop({ _id: false, type: [PetsSchema] })
  pets: Types.Array<Pet>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `members` prop is not a simple array. It is a collection of sub docs and should be declared as `[SchemaTypes.ObjectId]` which will implement sub documents with `_id` field via default mongo `ObjectID` value:

```
@Prop({ type: [SchemaTypes.ObjectId], ref: 'GuildMember'})
members: GuildMember[]
```

Comment: Okey, I have also found an answer for this question (should post it in couple of hours), but what I do want to use `SchemaTypes.ObjectId` for `_id` field for my `array of objects/docs`? Is there any option, like: `_id: false` ?

Comment: I dont get your question, sorry. Could be you be more specific ?

Comment: I mean that, as far as I know, an array of documents can use *build-in _id field with generated Object_id values by mongo itself*. In my case, I generate the `_id` field for subdocuments by myself and don't want to generate it by mongo. So my question is: **How with this solution achieve non generated, but manual determination of `_id` for sub-documents?**

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do that within mongoose. Maybe use some 3rd party lib like `class-transformer` ? see some use-cases in nestjs doc: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen this before. It deserves to take a look.