# How to properly type array of object IDs in mongoose with Typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Post Model:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema<IPost>(
  {
    // ...
    likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    // ...
  }
)

export default model<IPost>("Post", PostSchema)
```

```
export interface IPost {
  // ...
  likes: ObjectId[]
  // ...
}

export interface IPostDocument extends Document, IPost {}
```

And I'm trying to toggle a user like:

```
export const toggleLike: TController = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = req.user as IUserDocument;
  const userId = user._id;
  const postId = req.params.postId;
  try {
    const disliked = await PostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: postId, likes: userId },
      { $pull: { likes: userId } }
    ); // works with no problem
    if (disliked)
      res.json({ message: `User ${userId} disliked post ${postId}` });
    else {
      const liked = await PostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: postId },
        { $push: { likes: userId } }
      ); // the $push throws an error "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."
      if (liked) res.json({ message: `User ${userId} liked post ${postId}` });
      else return next(createError(404, "Post not found"));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(createError(500, error as Error));
  }
};
```

The mongo $push operator is throwing an error "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

I doubt it helps but the description of the error is:

*(property) likes?: _AllowStringsForIds<(((((((((((... | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[]> | ArrayOperator<(_AllowStringsForIds<(((((((((((... | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[])[] | any[]> | undefined)[]> | undefined*

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Would you mind sharing sample data in valid JSON format?

Comment: The error is indicating the data in the database is not a single level array, but an array of arrays.  Actually probably an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of arrays... of arrays... etc.

Comment: could you add details of your dependencies versions? I created a minimal reproduction [here](https://gist.github.com/diedu89/2f430fc90f36db87fb7215f64cc1dad8) and it's working for me with `"mongoose": "^6.0.11"`, `"@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97"`, and `"typescript": "^4.4.4"`

Comment: Thanks for your comments but this is resolved. On my interface I was using ObjectId but wasn't importing it from anywhere. Once I imported it from mongoose everything worked. I have no idea what is the other ObjectId I was using...

Answer (score 5):

I guess your question is very relevant to this one mine: [Nestjs: Correct schema for array of subdocuments in mongoose (without default _id or redefine ObjectId)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044809/nestjs-mongoose-schema-decorators-with-array-subdocument-field-without-defau). Except I don't want to have `ObjectID` but you are.

The problem is that `MongooseDocument<Array>` and TS `Array` are pretty the same, but have different methods.

I am working with Nestjs, so I will provide an example for it, but I guess you found my example very useful.

For example, for array of embed documents you need to have the following schema interface:

In child schema:

```
@Schema()
class Field extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId })
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId

  @Prop({ type: String })
  name: string;
}

export const FieldSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Field);
```

In parent schema:

```
  @Prop({ _id: true, type: [FieldSchema] })
  field: MongooseSchema.Types.Array<Field>;
```

And the most important part are imports:

```
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema, Types } from "mongoose";
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
```

Of course in the default TS project, without Nest.js you don't have `nest/mongoose` but as you may already understand, everything is relevant with interfaces and its types we are taking from `mongoose` itself.

So `class` is a Schema interface, which is extended from mongoose `Document` interface and all the arrays are not just plain TS arrays, but Schema.Types.Array (from mongoose). You may also use not just `ObjectId`, but other special Mongo only types, like `Decimal128` numbers and `Mixed` and so on, [according to the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

So in your case with Arrays of ObjectIds, you just need to use:

```
MongooseSchema.Types.Array<MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId>
```

[image: ArrayOfObjectIds]

or a bit more primitive way:

[image: ArrayOfObjectIds2]

> *In Nest in @Prop decorator you provide type for mongoDB field type, so it's the same as default TS: `new Schema({ languages: { type: ObjectId} })`*

So I hope it will help you in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Importing ObjectId from mongoose on my interface declaration solved the issue. Before that, I was using it but without importing it from anywhere (I didn't even know what that was).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but it might be interesting with: The type script side might be expecting other items to come there, because it's focused as an array.

Could you try to use each
{ $push: { : { $each: [ ,  ... ] } } }

value1 is enough on your position